# c++,フレンドクラスの使おうとすると認識できない型です、というエラー出る。原因

Tags: c++

フレンドクラスでなぜ前方宣言をしてるのに認識できない型ですとコンパイルエラー出るのか教えてほしいです。ちなみにコメント部の部分にclass fri{}コードを移動させるとコンパイル成功します。

```
class base;
class fri {
public:
    fri() { }

    void f(base& x) { cout << x.t; }
};

class fri;
class base {
    friend class fri;

private:
    int t;

protected:
    enum tmp { e_a , e_b, e_c };

public:
    //void fri::f();

    base(int x) { t = x; }
    ~base(){ }

    void f()
    {
        int x = e_a;
        cout <<"x:"<< x;
    }

};

//////////ここに書く
int main() {
    base b(100);
    fri x;
    x.f(b);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: class A{ friend class B;};は「BはAの全てのメンバを参照してよい」という意味です。他人classのメンバを実装したり宣言したりできるわけではありません。そういう質問の意図に感じられます。

Comment: そうなのはわかるのですがなぜエラーになるかがわかりません。

Comment: エラーメッセージをよく読んでいますか？どの行でどんなメッセージが出ているかを読めば、大抵分かります。エラーメッセージは重要ですので、質問文に追記してください。それでも分からなければ、前方宣言について調べてみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのエラーの原因は`friend`とは関係がありません。

```
class base;
class fri {
public:
    fri() { }

    void f(base& x) { cout << x.t; }
};
```

メンバー関数`f`の中で`base`クラスを使っていますが、この段階では、`base`という名前のクラスがあると宣言しているだけで、具体的に、`base`にどんなメンバーがあるかは定義されていません。定義されていないのにメンバー変数`t`にアクセスしようとしているので、エラーになっています。

コメント部分でに`fri`の定義を移動するとエラーがなくなるのは、コメントのところでは既に`base`が定義されているからです。

別の解決方法として、`fri::f()`の中身をコメント部分に持ってくるという方法があります。つまり、`class fri`の定義部分を

```
class base;
class fri {
public:
    fri() { }

    void f(base& x);
};
```

とし、メンバー関数の本体部分のコードをコメント部分に置きます。

```
void fri::f(base& x)
{
    cout << x.t;
}
```

いずれにせよ、`t`をアクセスするのは、`base`の定義が終わった後でなければなりません。

---

`friend`は、アクセス権を持たない外部のクラスや関数に、アクセスを許可するものです。アクセスを許可されても、どんなメンバーがあるか知らなければ、そもそもアクセスできません。

Comment: 前方宣言class fri{}の上にclass base;と関数のプロトタイプ宣言ように前方宣言をしているのでこれにより知られていると解釈したのですがコメント部の方に場所を移動させるほかないのでしょうか？

Comment: @matsuzawa 関数の場合は、戻り値と引数さえわかれば十分です。呼び出し側が関数の本体に直接アクセスするわけではないからです。今回の場合は、クラスインスタンスの中身に直接アクセスしています。関数のプロトタイプと同じ考え方は、全くできません。

Comment: つまり、フレンドクラスはコメント部の方に書くしか解決法がないということでしょうか？質問なのですが、フレンドクラスの定義にはコメントで//フレンドクラスですと書いておくしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: フレンドクラスを実用するってことは、つまりあるクラスのメンバを、フレンドクラスのメンバ関数中から使うということになるわけです。よってクラス定義の中でインラインに関数を書こうとすると必ずどっちかのメンバ定義が（その時点では）不可視ということになります。なのでクラス定義中にはメンバ関数の宣言だけを書いて、両方のクラスの定義が明らかになったのちにメンバ関数の実装を書くしかありません。